# Find single nearest point of point in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-spatial

I have an app that formerly used PostgreSQL with PostGIS but now the environment changes and I have to use MySql.

In my app i had a database query that searches the nearest point to a point. Note that my table has about 40 Million rows.

```
SELECT 
    strength, 
    created, 
    updated, 
    point,
    ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_GeomFromText('Point(:lat :long)'), point) AS distance
FROM signalstrengths
ORDER BY distance ASC
LIMIT 1;`;
```

I read that mysql can't use postgres' <-> operator and the above query is what I came up with through reading docs and SO.

But this query doesn't work and I'm concerned that the speed of the query will suffer from changing to MySql (from what I've read).

Can you help me fixing that query and tell me more about the speed differences?

Comment: Which version of MySQL do you use?

Comment: I would have suggested using ROWNUMBER() but it seems that function doesn't work in mysql...

Comment: @DPSSparial I.think you meant 'I would have suggested <name_any_useful_function>, but it seems that finction doesn't work in MySQL' ... you could maybe try to create a rectangle around your point to feed the seemingly index driven `MBR<function>` family, in order to get a small subset of points to calculate the distance on?

Comment: There's quite a bit written on the subject of efficiently finding nearest points on a sphere (or even the ellipsoid). Maybe consider using GIS packages in other languages to find a faster solution? MySQL may not be the right tool for this job.

Comment: @Mesa I'm using MariaDB 10.1.22

Comment: @barrycarter I can't use anything else than MySQL unfortunately

Comment: @TimoJokinen Can you use a procedural language around MySQL? And, just to confirm, you have to use a database (no command line programs allowed, no websites allowed, etc)? Also, can you pretend the Earth is a sphere, or is ellipsoid-iilty important here?